# How to fix "Run-time error '380': Could not set the RowSource property."

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the exact same code below for different sheets and it works correctly, but when I edited it for a new set of sheets in the same workbook the Run Time error comes up.

```
Private Sub cmdSearchKitDesc_Click()

Dim RowNum As Long
Dim SearchRow As Long

RowNum = 3
SearchRow = 3

Worksheets("Kit_database").Activate

Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Cells(RowNum, 3).Value, txtKitKeyword.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 4).Value = Cells(RowNum, 4).Value
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 5).Value = Cells(RowNum, 6).Value
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 6).Value = Cells(RowNum, 8).Value
        Worksheets("Kit_search").Cells(SearchRow, 7).Value = Cells(RowNum, 9).Value
        SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
    End If
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop
If SearchRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "No kits were found that match your criteria."
    Exit Sub
End If

lstKitResult.RowSource = "KitKit"

End Sub
```

I have changed RowNum to 3 to match the column of the sheet (in this case I would like to search the description of a kit) I would like to search and respectively in the string. I have carefully checked that the sheets and OFFSET function that it uses are named correctly.

The list box I would like to populate uses, 
`lstKitResult.RowSource = "KitKit"` where "KitKit" uses the following OFFSET formula,
`=OFFSET(Kit_search!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA(Kit_search!$C:$C)-1,6)`

The "Kit_database" sheet holds all the different types of kits I would search from. The "Kit_search" sheet is a placeholder for all the results found that match the kit description searched. The OFFSET function pulls data "Kit_search" that should be populated with the search results of `txtKitKeyword.Value`

I have tried different column numbers and sheet names to make sure that things match up but the Run Time error always comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what "KitKit" is. You would need to set the RowSourceType to correctly interpret the value. If you set it to "Value List" then the list would contain only "KitKit". So I must assume that you are trying to use a Table\Query or Field List. It sounds like you're saying "KitKit" is a named range that points to an offset formula. That would indeed be an error. The result of "KitKit" must contain and answer formatted to match the RowSourceType.

```
lstKitResult.RowSourceType = "Field List"
```

From the documentation:

> The RowSource property setting depends on the RowSourceType property
>   setting. For this RowSourceType setting   Enter this RowSource setting

```
Table/Query     A table name, query name, or SQL statement.
Value List      A list of items with semicolons (;) as separators.
Field List      A table name, query name, or SQL statement.
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.rowsource

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As per your comment, I have "KitKit" in my Name Manager that refers to the OFFSET function I mentioned. I understand that this "KitKit" is a 'Table/Query or Field List' on a different sheet named "Kit_search". I have tried your suggestion but another error comes up: `Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch`.

Comment: That's progress. Now you need to make the type you are passing to rowsource match what you declared. Your formula isn't "A table name, query name, or SQL statement.", it's a formula. So "KitKit" needs to be the name of a table, not a named range. Remove that named range. Select the data you want to use and press "CRTL+T" to make a table. Then give the table the name "KitKit"

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that I am working with a dynamic range? I'm not sure if this will change how things work. As I search for a kit description in my Kit_database, any kit with matching keywords will be placed in Kit_search where lstKitResult should populate the UserForm.

Comment: So the `RowSource` need to point to the query that provides the list from the DB. Then you can set your type to query, target the query. Boom. No more formulas, no more offset, no more errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to have the RowSource refer to the database table directly and populate my list box. However I still need to search by keyword, any way I can include this in the code?

Comment: Use a query. Build a query in the DB then point your rowsource to the query. You can do all the wizardry you want in SQL.

Comment: No, I guess you could build it in Excel with PowerQuery: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605